# Update package-lock.json without `npm install`

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I use symlinks in the `node_modules` directory for local development.

And I use `package-lock.json` when pushing to Heroku/Dokku.

When updating the dependencies, I want to update `package-lock.json` without removing my symlinks and running `npm install`.

Is there a recommended way to achieve this?

Otherwise, I'll just write a script that does `git checkout` and runs `npm install` on a temporary branch, before pushing.

Comment: That's a quite good question, wonder there is no answers. It's also actual if you do use yarn on your local machine, and npm on CI server